# How do I read/access name:values of Objects stored within an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How do I access the name:values of each Object stored within the randomImage.images Array?

I tried using a **for in** loop (see the randomImage.imagePicker Method for reference) but the output I get is:

```
0[object Object]
1[object Object]
2[object Object]
3[object Object]
```

---

```
(function() {

var randomImage = {

        images : [
                { 'image 1' : 'http://placehold.it/100x100'},
                { 'image 2' : 'http://placehold.it/200x200'},
                { 'image 3' : 'http://placehold.it/300x300'},
                { 'image 4' : 'http://placehold.it/400x400'}
                ],//images Array
        imagePicker : function () {
                        for (var k in this.images ) {
                            console.log(k+this.images[k]);
                        }
                }//imagePicker Method

}//randomImage Object

randomImage.imagePicker()

})()
```

Comment: try making a global reference to images and inspecting it with Google Chrome Developer tools.  You can add a watch under Source and see the complete structure of the object.  That will tell you if what you want is available or not.

Comment: Are the objects really needed? Why don't you store the image urls directly in the array? `images: [ "http://...", "http://...", ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is like that :

```js
(function() {

var randomImage = {

        images : [
                { 'image 1' : 'http://placehold.it/100x100'},
                { 'image 2' : 'http://placehold.it/200x200'},
                { 'image 3' : 'http://placehold.it/300x300'},
                { 'image 4' : 'http://placehold.it/400x400'}
                ],//images Array
        imagePicker : function () {
                        for (var k in this.images ) {
                            
                            var curImg = this.images[k];
                            var key = Object.keys(curImg)[0];
                            
                          console.log(k+this.images[k]);

                          msg = k + ' : ' + key + ' => ' + curImg[key];
                          document.getElementById('el').innerHTML+='<div>'+msg+'<div>';
                        }
                }//imagePicker Method

}//randomImage Object

randomImage.imagePicker()

})()
```

```html
<div id ='el'><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `for...in` loops to iterate arrays.

You can get the enumerable own properties of an object with `Object.keys`.

```
randomImage.images.forEach(function(obj) {
  var prop = Object.keys(obj)[0],
      value = obj[prop];
  console.log(prop, value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the values using a `forEach` loop.

```
this.images.forEach(function(image){
    for(var key in image) {
        console.log('key', key);
        console.log('value', image[key]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use console.log(k,this.images[k]);    ( Comma and not plus sign)

and you will get output as :

```
0 Object {image 1: "http://placehold.it/100x100"}
1 Object {image 2: "http://placehold.it/200x200"}
2 Object {image 3: "http://placehold.it/300x300"}
3 Object {image 4: "http://placehold.it/400x400"}
```

Comment: OP wants to access the key/value directly, not as an object.

Answer (score 0):

One more option. For the structure you have now you need two loops. One to loop through the images array and another loop to access the keys.

```js
imagePicker : function () {

    for ( var i=0, len=this.images.length; i<len; i++ ) {

        var imgObj = this.images[ i ];

        for ( var key in imgObj ) {
            console.log( key + imgObj[ key ] );
        }

    }
}
```

Though I wonder if you could get away with just using an array to store your image URLs.

```js
images: [
    'http://placehold.it/100x100',
    'http://placehold.it/200x200',
    'http://placehold.it/300x300',
    'http://placehold.it/400x400'
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function() {
  var i = 0;
  var len = this.images.length;
  //loop through the images
  for (i; i < len; i++) {
    // access the Image object
    var oImage = this.images[i];
    // get the keys of the Image object
    var aKeys = Object.keys(oImage);
    // log the url of the image by accessing the first key
    console.log(oImage[aKeys[0]]);
  }
}
```

A better solution would be to design a better data model like:

```
var images = [
 {
   name: 'image 1',
   url: '//placehold.it/100x100'
 }
 ...
]
```

And access the Image name and url like:

```
function() {
  var i = 0;
  var len = this.images.length;

  for (i; i < len; i++) {
    var oImage = this.images[i];
    console.log(oImage.url, oImage.name);
  }
}
```